# I have entered glutPostRedisplay(); but it does not refresh the window and/or the output?

Tags: c, opengl, cross-platform, glut

When I try to run this code it just posts the output after the exit function I don't why it just doesnt work. I know the code is long because I am making a game whilst learning OpenGL, and I am trying to make it cross-platform as possible.The line 80 isnt executed until the window is closed.
Can someone figure out and fix the problem , or is it because of my weird game design?

If its a compatibility issue here are the specs:

ArchLinux(x86_64) with xfce4
the compiler is gcc

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef WIN32 // Will need this later
#include <io.h>
#include <windows.h>
#elif _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 199309L
#include <time.h>   // for nanosleep
#include <unistd.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h> // for usleep
#endif

/**
    By default it should be 
    UP - move on negative z axis
    DOWN - move on positive z axis
    LEFT - move left relative to the camera (mostly negative x axis)
    RIGHT - move right relative to the camera (mostly positive x axis)
    SPACE - jump (fxp. decreasing the Z value)
**/

unsigned char controls[5],areyougoingtoexit;
unsigned char configurationdone,ingame = 0;
FILE *configuration;
unsigned short displayx,displayy,displaymode;
int winIDMain;

void mainmenurender(void);

void mainmenukeyboard(unsigned char c, int x, int y);

void mainmenumouse(int button, int state, int x, int y);

idle(void){ //To prevent compilation errors ,thats why I puted it infront of the code
    glutSetWindow(winIDMain);
    glutPostRedisplay();

}

int main(int argc, char* argv) {
    while(1){
        if(configurationdone){
        glutInit(&argc, argv);
            glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);
            glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
            glutInitWindowSize(displayx, displayy);
        winIDMain = glutCreateWindow("GL Game");

            if(ingame == 0){
                glutSetWindow(winIDMain);
                glutDisplayFunc(mainmenurender);       
                glutKeyboardFunc(mainmenukeyboard);
                glutMouseFunc(mainmenumouse);
                glutIdleFunc (idle);
            }
            if(displaymode == 1){
                glutFullScreen();
            }

            glutMainLoop(); 
        }else{
            loadconfiguration();
        }
    }
}

void mainmenukeyboard(unsigned char c, int x, int y) {
        if (c == 27) {
        if(displaymode == 1)
                    displaymode == 0;
        else
            displaymode == 1;
        }
}


void mainmenumouse(int button, int state, int x, int y) {
    int perpartpixels = glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT) / 40; //Aproxx 5% of the resolution 
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON){
        printf("X:%d Y:%d",x,y);
        if((y >= perpartpixels * 3 && y <= perpartpixels * 3 + 15) && (x >= 0 && x <= 81)){
            printf("Play");
        }else if((y >= perpartpixels * 4 && y <= perpartpixels * 4 + 15) && (x >= 0 && x <= 72)){
            printf("Settings");
        }else if((y >= perpartpixels * 5 && y <= perpartpixels * 5 + 15) && (x >= 0 && x <= 36)){
            exit(0);
        }
    }        
    if (button == GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON) {
                exit(0);
        }
}

void mainmenurender(void) {
    glutSetWindow(winIDMain);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity ();

    char mainmenustring[9] = "Main Menu";
    glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
    glRasterPos2f(-1, 0.9);
    int mainmenulen, mainmenui;
    mainmenulen = (int)strlen(mainmenustring);
    for (mainmenui = 0; mainmenui < mainmenulen; mainmenui++) {
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15, mainmenustring[mainmenui]);
    }
    char startstring[5] = "Start";
    glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
    glRasterPos2f(-1, 0.8);
    int startlen, starti;
    startlen = (int)strlen(startstring);
    for (starti = 0; starti < startlen; starti++) {
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15, startstring[starti]);
    }
    char settingsstring[8] = "Settings";
    glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
    glRasterPos2f(-1, 0.75);
    int settingslen, settingsi;
    settingslen = (int)strlen(settingsstring);
    for (settingsi = 0; settingsi < settingslen; settingsi++) {
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15, settingsstring[settingsi]);
    }
    char exitstring[9] = "Exit";
    glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
    glRasterPos2f(-1, 0.7);
    int exitlen, exiti;
    exitlen = (int)strlen(exitstring);
    for (exiti = 0; exiti < exitlen; exiti++) {
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15, exitstring[exiti]);
    }
        glutSwapBuffers();
}






// Load config functions
int loadconfiguration(void) {
    //Default variables
    char defaultcontrolconfig[5] = { 0x18, 0x19, 0x1A, 0x1B, 0x20 }; //UP,DOWN,LEFT,RIGHT,SPACE(JUMP)
    unsigned short defaultx = 640,defaulty = 480,defaultmode = 0; //X RES,Y RES, FULLSCREENMODE (0 NO ,1 YES)
    //Check if config folder is present otherwise create it 
    int result = mkdir("configuration", 0777);
    if(result == -1){
        printf("Ignore creating folder:\nError -1 Directory already exists\n");
    }else if(result != 0){
        printf("Error: %d while creating configuration folder\n", result);
    }
    //Check if control configuration is present otherwise create it
    if (access("configuration/controls.conf",F_OK)!= -1)
    {
        printf ("Found controls configuration file\n");
        configuration = fopen("configuration/controls.conf", "rb");
    }
    else
    {
        configuration = fopen("configuration/controls.conf", "wb");
        fwrite(defaultcontrolconfig,1,5,configuration);
    }
    fread(controls,1,5,configuration);
    printf("Finished loading controls configuration\n");
    fclose(configuration);

    //Check if display configuration is present otherwise create it
    if (access("configuration/display.conf",F_OK)!= -1)
    {
        printf ("Found display configuration file\n");
        configuration = fopen("configuration/display.conf", "rb");
    }
    else
    {
        configuration = fopen("configuration/display.conf", "wb");
        fprintf(configuration,"%hd\n%hd\n%hd",defaultx,defaulty,defaultmode);
    }
    rewind(configuration);
    fscanf(configuration,"%hd\n%hd\n%hd",&displayx,&displayy,&displaymode);
    printf("Finished loading display configuration\n");
    fclose(configuration);


    printf("Finished loading configurations\n");
    configurationdone = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself.The program can only output in glut Display Function (what am I actually talking about is glutDisplayFunc();).

Comment: Still your code is quite WTF worthy? Why that while(configurationdone) loop in main? Just call into glutMainLoop already and do all required configuration in idle; You can change the callback hooks at any time, so it's perfectly valid to first set the idle callback function to a configuration function and end the configuration with setting the idle callback to your game idle and call glutPostRedisplay. Of course if your configuration takes some time you should break it down into multiple steps and give the user feedback every few 100ms.

Comment: @datenwolf You're kinda right, I should clean up my code.